# Passing a custom field value to cart in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, custom-fields

I have a variable in my simple.php template that I want to pass through to display in the cart.

How do I set this as a custom field within simple.php and then retrieve the value attached to that product id in the cart?

Comment: Please add what you have tried and what your code is

Comment: @SuitBoyApps Whole paragraphs of code added to the functions file but it hasnt rendered anything out at all. Im new to using hooks so finding it a little confusing. I have a custom price calculation in my single product so need to pass that to the cart, or override the product price with this one.